# What is the meaning of _ENV["HTTP_X_VARNISH"] values I get using phpinfo()

Tags: php, magento, caching, varnish

When I run `echo phpinfo()` in root of application(Magento).
I get `_ENV["HTTP_X_VARNISH"]   1321634895`

This means varnish cache is installed on server but what does *1321634895* value means.
Do we have some default value for the same.

Please help me to understand this.

Comment: it must be any of the parameters defined on the following tutorial, http://helpdesk.getpantheon.com/customer/portal/articles/425726

Comment: @SKV pls i need more detailed information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HTTP_X_VARNISH` is just an internal ID of Varnish used to reference requests. You can use it for debugging purposes as [the documentation says](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/2.1/faq/http.html).